# Remove contact from GAL in Exchange 2010

Tags: exchange-2010, exchange

I'm looking to remove contacts that were created in MS Exchange 2010 from showing up in the Default GAL, they are shared through an address list called "Shared". I have two groups of people. Group one I don't want to be able to see these contacts (or the Default GAL at all is also fine). Group two I want to be able to see the contacts through "Shared", it is fine for this group to be able to see the Default GAL but could also be taken away as well. When I edit the permissions to opening the GAL in ADSI Edit it will remove it, but will also remove all other address lists that I don't want removed from that group. Hopefully this is enough information, I have been seeing that people say not to touch the GAL so I've avoided changing it's recipient settings.
Thanks everyone

Answer (score -1):

Here is one solution to your problem - [link](http://translate.google.com/translate?js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&sl=pt&tl=en&u=http://alexmnoronha.wordpress.com/2011/01/27/criando-uma-lista-de-endereos-global-personalizada-no-exchange-server-2010/)

It's a Google Translated link, but the translation is good.

Comment: Please provide answers, not links (even if the links may contain the answer). A link to an answer is not an answer.